# Selenium button click in loop fails after first try

Tags: python, selenium, web, text, web-crawler

Currently I am working on a web crawler that should be able to download text of a dutch newspaper bank. The first link is working correctly but suddenly the second link creates an error of which I do not know how to fix this.

It seems that selenium is unable to click the button in the second link while it succeeds doing so in the first link.

Do you know what causes the second link (telegraaf page) to fail?

UPDATE CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#Set up the path to the chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

all_details = []
for c in range(1,2):
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.delpher.nl/nl/kranten/results?query=kernenergie&facets%5Bpapertitle%5D%5B%5D=Algemeen+Dagblad&facets%5Bpapertitle%5D%5B%5D=De+Volkskrant&facets%5Bpapertitle%5D%5B%5D=De+Telegraaf&facets%5Bpapertitle%5D%5B%5D=Trouw&page={}&sortfield=date&cql%5B%5D=(date+_gte_+%2201-01-1970%22)&cql%5B%5D=(date+_lte_+%2201-01-2018%22)&coll=ddd".format(c))
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        incategory = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("search-result")
        print(driver.current_url)
        
        links = [ i.find_element_by_class_name("thumbnail search-result__thumbnail").get_attribute("href") for i in incategory]
            
        # Lets loop through each link to acces the page of each book
        for link in links:
            # get one book url
            driver.get(link)
                      
            # newspaper 
            newspaper = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/div/div[2]/header/h1/span[2]")
            
            # date of the article
            date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/div/div[2]/header/div/ul/li[1]")
            
            #click button and find title
            div_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="object"]/div/div/div')))
            hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(div_element)
            hover.perform()
            div_element.click()
            
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="object-viewer__ocr-button"]')))
            hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button)
            hover.perform()

            button.click()
            
            element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".object-viewer__ocr-panel-results")
            driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", element)
            
            # content of article
                        
            try:
                content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'kernenergie')]").text
                
            except:
                content = None
                
            # Define a dictionary with details we need
            r = {
                "1Newspaper":newspaper.text,
                "2Date":date.text,
                "3Content":content,
            }
            # append r to all details
            all_details.append(r)
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass
            
# save the information into a CSV file
df = pd.DataFrame(all_details)
df = df.to_string()

time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have some problems.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Should only be used once

```
 links = [ i.find_element_by_class_name("search-result__thumbnail-link").get_attribute("href") for i in incategory]
```

Is a more useful way to get all links

```
print(driver.current_url)
```

Could replace

```
 print("https://www.delpher.nl/nl/kranten/results?query=kernenergie&facets%5Bpapertitle%5D%5B%5D=Algemeen+Dagblad&facets%5Bpapertitle%5D%5B%5D=De+Volkskrant&facets%5Bpapertitle%5D%5B%5D=De+Telegraaf&facets%5Bpapertitle%5D%5B%5D=Trouw&page={}&sortfield=date&cql%5B%5D=(date+_gte_+%2201-01-1970%22)&cql%5B%5D=(date+_lte_+%2201-01-2018%22)&coll=ddd".format(c))
```

No need for url=link

```
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
```

Your title actually doesn't get on the second page. Use something like this for all values.

```
        try:
            content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="object-viewer__ocr-panel"]/div[2]/div[5]').text
        except:
            content = None

        # Define a dictionary 
        r = {
            "1Newspaper":newspaper,
            "2Date":date,
            "3Title": title,
            "4Content": content,
        }
```

You can replace your exception with to figure out the line of problem.

```
except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass
```

Comment: What I'd suggest right now is when you look for your elements either set it to it's .text or just set it to None.

Comment: will do, meanwhile I think i found the error. The presence of element located currently refers to an ID which is present before loading, will implement a div class & style element that only displays after loading thus showing the button.

Comment: It seems now that selenium is unable to open the retrieved links, do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: The links are fine they print out.

Comment: It fails to open the collected links associated with the following error:

'WebElement' object has no attribute 'WebDriverWait'

Comment: I have updated the code so you can see how i implemented your advice

Comment: Oh you don't need the webdriver wait.

Comment: That's really only used on finding elements.

Comment: It suddenly seems to work now haha! Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: No problem if my answer helped please check mark it.

Answer (score 0):

it might be that the button you are trying to reach is inside an iframe, which means you have to access that one before searching for the XPATH:

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
```

`driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`

Also there might be a possibility the object youre trying to click is not visible yet, which could be solved by an timeout

Comment: Thanks, but inspecting the page does not show any (i)frame element as far as i can see.